# floating problems

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some weird problems trying to float stuff to the left. I tried to clear it with the [easy clearing method](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) but its still not working. See any problems? I'm trying to float `article`

Heres the CSS

```
    #main-wrap { margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; }

/* Navigation */
nav { background: #2f2f2f; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  float: right; width: 473px; }
nav ul { padding: 10px; }
nav ul li { display: inline; border-right: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #686868; margin: 0 -4px 0 0; padding: 0 14px 0 14px; }
nav ul li:first-child { border-left: none; }
nav ul li:last-child { border-right: none; }
nav ul li a { color: #fff; letter-spacing: 1px; text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #000; }

/* Logo */

#logo-wrap { background: url(../images/logo.png); display: block; position: relative; right: 156px; top: 2px; z-index: -1; height: 718px; width: 733px; }

/* Main Content */

article { float: right; width: 482px; }
```

[Heres the HTML.](http://pastebin.com/UWvzKqWb)

`#logo-wrap` is just one big image.

Comment: HTML code might come in handy..

Comment: I posted it in a link 2 pastebin

Comment: Sorry if the post wasn't clear enough. I'm trying to float article but it just won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about set

```
article { float: left; width: 482px; }
```

to float: left; and not float: right; ?

look here:
http://jsbin.com/ofizu5/2

Hope this will help you? If not describe a bit more precise your problem :)

Comment: No, it still doesn't look right. I'm trying to float it left, beside #logo-wrap. When I add clearfix to #main-wrap, article goes back in the wrapper but it still doesn't go up.I assume its because #logo-wrap is larger and its blocking it. But I did use z-index to bring the article up a couple layers but that still didn't work. I also tried relative positioning article but theres a big gap on the bottom of the page....

Comment: Well, the Logo-wrap has a width of 733px; and the article has a width of 482px and your main wrap only has a width of 960px. And 733px + 482px is bigger than 960px. So the article doesn't float right next to the logo-wrap